# Windows service installation - complex displayname not present on services list

Tags: c#, windows, list, winapi, service

These are 4 calls of the same method different only by parameters:

```
SynchronizationServiceController.InstallAndStart("test", "test", path);
SynchronizationServiceController.InstallAndStart("test1", "test1", path);
SynchronizationServiceController.InstallAndStart("test2", "\"Usługa synchronizacji systemu B2B1\"", path);
SynchronizationServiceController.InstallAndStart(serviceName, "Usługa synchronizacji systemu B2B", path);
```

By trial and error I've managed to find that "Display service name" param (lpDisplayName [in, optional]) of [CreateService](http://www.example.com/) method is the cause of the issue. If its short and simple (no spaces(even with escaped brackets) and diacritic marks) svc shows up on services list (case 1 and 2). Otherwise it is installed **properly** and **can be managed**(start/stop/uninstall) programatically without any errors, however I cant see it on the list.

This is the install method code:

```
public static void InstallAndStart(string serviceName, string displayName, string fileName)
    {
        IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.AllAccess);

        try
        {
            IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.AllAccess);

            if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                service = CreateService(scm, serviceName, displayName, ServiceAccessRights.AllAccess, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, ServiceBootFlag.AutoStart, ServiceError.Normal, fileName, null, IntPtr.Zero, null, null, null);
```

but as I say - it **works**. I just cant see my services on the list.

Comment: Are you sure that the encoding of the file produced the correct encoding in the IL-Code? I suggest to write the characters via the [`\uxxxx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669) encoding in the string literal, to be sure that it will mapped to the correct characters... Alternatively you must be sure that your source file is saved as "UTF-8" or "UNICODE" (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0kyekyh)

Comment: I don't know if is it me being blind, or some System problems issued yesterday. I've tried using unicode encoding etc. yesterday and everything worked as a charm. Today suddenly my problem disappeared and original "service display name" is visible (without encoding). Anyway thanks.

Comment: Only thing that didnt work was:
SynchronizationServiceController.InstallAndStart("u0142u0020u0105", "\u0142\u0020\u0105", path); getting error 1078 (wrong service name or display name) which is also returned when you try to install two services with not unique displayname/name. If names are the same -> service is already installed. If displayname is equal to name of existing svc - you get error 1078.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the encoding of the file produced the correct encoding in the IL-Code?

I suggest to write the characters via the \uxxxx encoding in the string literal, to be sure that it will mapped to the correct characters...

Alternatively you must be sure that your 
[source file is saved as UTF-8 or UNICODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0kyekyh)